# How to Translate Gender In Detail Order Page

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, translation

I try translate Gender, Date Of Birth And TAX/VAT in Order Detail Page.
(/admin/sales_order/view/order_id)

I Trying, in app - locale - pt_Br - Mage_Customer.csv

I Trying in app - design - frontend - default - 2012 - template - customer - widget - gender.phtml

I Trying in app - design - frontend - default - 2012 - template - customer - widget - taxvat.phtml.phtml

Answer (score 0):

- Set the locale for your admin store (Default Configuration Scope) to "Portugese (Brazil)"

  - **System > Configuration > General > Locale Options > Locale**
- Clear the translation, configuration, and block_html caches in **System > Cache Management**
- Log out & log back in. Concluído.

Comment: Hello benmarks,

I was with the language set to Portuguese (Brazil) but still did not work.

Thanks for trying to help

Comment: The steps I've mentioned above do work (if you have pt_BR installed, which you do) OR you have a broken installation, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate directly on the page by enable the translate inline feature. To do this, access System >> Configuraition >> ADVANCED >> Developer >> Translate Inline >> Set to Yes in Enabled for Admin.

After that, your admin page looks different. Hover your pointer over the text, then a little book will appear, click it, then the pop up appear, you can translate the text here.

After you make changes, refresh the page to see the result.

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for trying to help, but these "labels" are not given the option Translate Inline in admin.

I had to do it via SQL.

Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem of translation. I had to do it via SQL, because it was something from the database.

I used the following code:

For TAX/VAT

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `frontend_label`='CPF/CNPJ' WHERE `frontend_label`='Tax/VAT Number';
```

For Gender

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `frontend_label`='Sexo' WHERE `frontend_label`='Gender';
```

For Date Of Birth

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `frontend_label`='Data de Nascimento' WHERE `frontend_label`='Date Of Birth';
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved simply modifying its related value into the database,

**table** `eav_attribute_option_value`

Anyway, This is a stupid limitation imposed by Magento community, like other million as this.